# IdentityServer4 Quickstart issues (self host server set up)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I am currently at this page of the IdentityServer 4
[guide](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) and I am trying to start the server.
[my properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2WFv.png)
However, when I run it, my browser pops up this page http://localhost:5000 and it is not available (not accessible as it there is no connection)
May I know how to host the server ? I follow the tutorial exactly

Comment: I went through the same tutorial yesterday.  I think something must have broken since their previous versions of the tutorial.  I am currently trying to compare my code that gets created by following their instructions in the tutorial, versus the code that exists in the Quickstart samples here:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts  ... I believe the problem may be due to the fact that the template does not create the required JSON in launchSettings.json (under the IdentityServer project, Properties... launchSettings.json).  Try the one in "samples"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did verify that if I use the JSON from the sample on Github it then hits the discovery endpoint correctly; replace the JSON created by the template, with this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "SelfHost": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: note this Quickstart is also slightly complicated by the fact that the API launchSettings.json also defaults to values which are not what you want - again check the samples on Github for a better working version.  Also it's complicated because it doesn't really say, but it appears to be true, that you need to set multiple startup projects in your VS solution (right-click on the solution, select Properties, then 'multiple startup projects' and ensure the API and IdentityServer both start; then you can right-click on the "Client" console app and say "Debug... start new instance" and step through

Comment: I'm new to this, thanks for your clear explanation on this issue, yaa the problem should be the launchsetting.json , and i tried to search around and recreated the project, and refer to your example above, now the server can run

Comment: great, glad to help!